# Oracle Materialized view VS Physical Table

Tags: database, performance, oracle, oracle11g

*Note: Oracle 11gR2 Standard version (so no partitioning)*

So I have to build a process to build reports off a table containing about 27 million records.  The  dilemma I'm facing is the fact that I can't create my own indexes off this table as it's a 3rd party table that we can't alter.    So, I started experimenting with the use of Materialized views where I can then create my own indexes, or a physical table that would basically just be a duplicate that  I'd truncate and repopulate on demand.

The advantage with the MAT view is that it's basically pulling from the "Live" table, so I don't have to worry about discrepancies as long as I refresh it  before use, the problem is the refresh seems to take a significant amount of time.   I then decided to try the physical table approach, where I tried truncating and repopulating (Took around 10 min), then rebuild indexes (which takes another 10, give or take).... I also tried updating with only "new" record by performing a:

```
INSERT... SELECT where NOT Exists (Select 1 from Table where PK = PK)
```

Which almost takes 10 min also regardless of my index, parallelism, etc...

Has anyone had to deal with this amount of data (which will keep growing) and found an approach that performs well and works efficiently??

Seems a view won't do.... so I'm left with those 2 options because I can't tweak indexes on my primary table, so any tips suggestions would be greatly appreciated... The whole purpose of this process was to make things "faster" for reporting, but somehow where I'm gaining performance in some areas, I end up losing in others given the amount of data I need to move around.  Are there other options aside from:

1. Truncate / Populate Table, Rebuild indexes
2. Populate secondary table from primary table where PK not exist
3. Materialized view (Refresh, Rebuild indexes)
4. View that pulls from Live table (No new indexes)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.....

Does anyone know if doing a "Create Table As Select..." perform better than "Insert... Select" if I render my indexes and such unusable when doing my insert on the second option, or should it be fairly similar?

Comment: Can you quantify "significant amount of time" to refresh the materialized view rather than using the physical table?  How are you refreshing the materialized view?  Are you doing a transactional refresh (delete and insert)?  Or are you doing a truncate and direct-path insert?  Can you create a materialized view log on the base table so that you can do an incremental refresh of the materialized view?

Comment: @JustinCave - Thanks for the response! Generally, the refresh took over 10 min also, which I simply did using the following: "DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(LIST=>'ASSUMPTION.GL_JLOG_UNBALANCED',PARALLELISM => 4);"... I'm fairly new to Oracle, so if there are alternative means, please tell me.  I actually disable logging (NOLOGGING) to my table prior to doing my insert on the physical table and make use of the APPEND and Parallel hints, which have helped. Logging is enabled on my primary table yes, so how can I do an incremental refresh like you suggest?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you aren't able to make indexes. It is possible to have the indexes in a different schema from the tables.

Comment: @AdamHawkes - Is that a question?  The primary table is under one schema where my "secondary" is in another... The primary already has some indexes based on the needs of the system using it, where my secondary table has indexing based on my reporting needs.  Not sure I understand what you're implying, can you elaborate?

Comment: @denisb - Nope, not a question. You stated "I can't create my own indexes off this table as it's a 3rd party table that we can't alter." You can create indexes on the primary table which reside in another schema.

Comment: @AdamHawkes - Oh sorry, YES, in theory I can, however because these tables don't belong to us and could affect the performance of the underlying system using them, if we modify them and something happens, the onus falls on us and they won't offer support on the system.  It's like putting an aftermarket exhaust on your car while you have warranty, most manufacturers will void it, same set of circumstances, which is why I need my own data set to work with.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Have you tried creating the MV with `REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT`? There are restrictions, but it may work in your case.

Comment: @AdamHawkes - I'm actually in the process of doing that now, created my MView log on that table to allow for fast / incremental refresh and will give it a try to see whether it does the trick, will keep you posted!  Thanks again for the info guys!

Comment: Hey guys, I think the MVIEW with "fast refresh" will do the trick here!  Should I put it on commit, or on demand?  I intend to force refresh on demand anyway, but just wondering what the "best practice" would be.  As far as indexes are concerned, should I also rebuild / gather stats on the MVIEW indexes prior to running my process, or is this different a methodology than from tables?

Comment: If you're not allowed to modify tables by adding indexes then I'd think that a materialized view log would also be a problem, especially ON COMMIT which will have a larger effect on performance than additional indexes. Your application's data changes will now have to wait on maintenance of the application table, of the application table's indexes, and of the materialized view log table and its index, and the commit will wait on execution of the query to modify the MV table, maintenance of the MV table's indexes, and maintenance of the MV log table and its indexes. Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

I think that there's a lot to be said for a very simple approach on this sort of task. Consider a truncate and direct path (append) insert on the duplicate table without disabling/rebuilding indexes, with NOLOGGING set on the table. The direct path insert has a index maintenance mechanism associated with it that is possibly more efficient than running multiple index rebuilds post-load, as it logs in temporary segments the data required to build the indexes and thus avoids subsequent multiple full table scans.

If you do want to experiment with index disable/rebuild then try rebuilding all the indexes at the same time without query parallelism, as only one physical full scan will be used -- the rest of the scans will be "parasitic" in that they'll read the table blocks from memory.

When you load the duplicate table consider ordering the rows in the select so that commonly used predicates on the reports are able to access fewer blocks. For example if you commonly query on date ranges, order by the date column. Remember that a little extra time spent in building this report table can be recovered in reduced report query execution time.

Consider compressing the table also, but only if you're loading with direct path insert unless you have the pricey Advanced Compression option. Index compression and bitmap indexes are also worth considering.

Also, consider not analyzing the reporting table. Report queries commonly use multiple predicates that are not well estimated using conventional statistics, and you have to rely on dynamic sampling for good cardinality estimates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Create Table As Select" generate lesser undo. That's an advantage.
When data is "inserted" indexes also are maintained and performance is impacted negatively.

Comment: The reduction in UNDO of CTAS is pretty small compared to truncate/direct path nologging insert though.